# Check visibility of an element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a variable called `object`. How can I check with JavaScript if it is visible?

I tried `!object.getAttribute("dislay", "none")`... but that doesn't work.

Could somebody help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if element is visible in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom)

Answer (score 21):

```
function isvisible(obj) {
  return obj.offsetWidth > 0 && obj.offsetHeight > 0;
}
```

as it's implemented in JQuery.

Answer (score 11):

If you use jQuery, the following will return true if the object is visible:

```
$(object).is(':visible');
```

If not, you can try these:

```
if (object.style['display'] != 'none')
```

But this will work only if `display:none` has been set explicitly on this object.

Comment: +1: As much as I'm normally against throwing jQuery at every JavaScript problem under the sun, especially for rendering issues it's IMO simply not worth reinventing the wheel without making it at least significantly better.

Answer (score 2):

To get value of a display style using javascript you can use:

IE:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').currentStyle.display
or
object.currentStyle.display
```

Others:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').getComputedStyle('display')
or
object.getComputedStyle('display')
```

Comment: With this I get: `"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'getComputedStyle'"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (object.style.visibility <> 'visible' || object.style.display == 'none')
```

If it doesn't work, try to use

```
 if (object.currentStyle.visibility <> 'visible' || object.currentStyle.display == 'none')
```

Comment: I've looked around a bit and can't find an explanation of what the "<>" syntax is.  I assume from context it tests for inequality, but why not just use "!="?  Does this do something different?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you're using the getAttribute method correctly. Try taking a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_getattribute.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/PEA4j/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            alert("Is #foo1 visible: " + $("#foo1").is(":visible") + "\nIs #foo2 visible: " + $("#foo2").is(":visible"));

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="foo1" style="display:none">foo1 display none</div>
<div id="foo2">foo2 no display property;</div>
</body>
</html>
```