# Check if element is visible in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there any way that I can check if an element is visible in pure JS (no jQuery) ?

So, given a DOM element, how can I check if it is visible or not? I tried:

```
window.getComputedStyle(my_element)['display']);
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.  I wonder which attributes should I check. It comes to my mind:

```
display !== 'none'
visibility !== 'hidden'
```

Any others that I might be missing?

Comment: That doesn't use display, it uses visibility so check for visibility (hidden or visible). ex: `document.getElementById('snDealsPanel').style.visibility`

Comment: PSL. If I would like to do this more general, which attributes should I check: visibility, display...?

Comment: You can make it generic in your own way but what i am saying is it uses visibility inspecting the element.

Comment: Here is my code (no jquery) for this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/22969337/2274995

Comment: 0 < document.querySelector('foo').getBoundingClientRect().height

Answer (score 945, accepted):

According to [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetParent), an element's `offsetParent` property will return `null` whenever it, or any of its parents, is hidden via the display style property.  Just make sure that the element isn't fixed.  A script to check this, if you have no `position: fixed;` elements on your page, might look like:

```
// Where el is the DOM element you'd like to test for visibility
function isHidden(el) {
    return (el.offsetParent === null)
}
```

On the other hand, if you *do* have position fixed elements that might get caught in this search, you will sadly (and slowly) have to use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle).  The function in that case might be:

```
// Where el is the DOM element you'd like to test for visibility
function isHidden(el) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    return (style.display === 'none')
}
```

Option #2 is probably a little more straightforward since it accounts for more edge cases, but I bet its a good deal slower, too, so if you have to repeat this operation many times, best to probably avoid it.

Comment: Wow no kidding.  Imo there should be no reason to use the second method as a universal solution; no page should have fixed elements that its creator isn't explicitly aware of, and one can just check those manually using the getComputedStyle() method after running the offsetParent method on all elements first.

Comment: Also FYI, just discovered that `el.offsetParent` wasn't working on IE9 for non-fixed elements. Or so it seems, anyway. (OK for IE11, though.) So went with `getComputedStyle` after all.

Comment: the MDN documentatio refered to says "This property will return null <b>on Webkit</b> if the element is hidden [...]". It also mentions IE9 but how about other browsers?

Comment: This solution doesn't work for sliders. Mainly slider libs use a mask layer to show the current item to the user and the element always has a parent and `offsetParent` is not empty.

Comment: Note that offsetParent is marked as causing reflow in browsers. Ref: http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/03/how-not-to-trigger-layout-in-webkit.html So, using the 2nd method will be effectively better.

Comment: @Ethan: not so sure, don't have anything to back this up, but I feel like `window.getComputedStyle()` does some extra calculation under the hood that slows it down.  Regardless, the jsPerf above speaks for itself...

Comment: @AlexZ I am not sure if offsetParent really does a reflow in today's browsers, but yes a couple of yrs back, they used to, that's what I understand from reports. Note that the jsPerf only mentions of the speed of execution, while reflow is about the display. And reflows does make the UI poor. I personally will not go for the speed for a routine that is probably called 5/6 times on a page.

Comment: Fair point about the reflow vs JS performance. I was under the impression that reflow-calling properties/methods were such because it was calculating their value that required the reflow, and that they would not be able to return until said reflow is complete. I could definitely be wrong though.  Either way, in the project I used this for, `offsetParent` poved to be much more performant from the UI standpoint (it was the only method that caused no visible lag).  Whether this was due to faster JS execution or less layout thrashing, I don't know.

Comment: alas! `getComputedStyle` does not work correctly: http://plnkr.co/edit/6CSCA2fe4Gqt4jCBP2wu?p=preview
However, so does `offsetParent` - perhaps a combination of the two should be used?

Comment: @guymograbi, I think getComputedStyle() works as specified: it tells you the _computed_ style of the element.  To figure out how the element is actually _rendered_, you would need to recurse through all of its parents.  On the other hand, I think offsetParent takes the rendered style into account.

Comment: @AlexZ I just wanted code like `$(..).is(':visible')` but without jquery.. you can see my answer as to what I used (simply copy pasted what jquery do) - no iteration on parents.. I think my solution answers all my use-cases but perhaps HommerSmith had other needs.

Comment: so sad this is still so complex

Comment: so for `getComputedStyle` we also have to check the whole parents dom tree?

Comment: for ie9+ie10 you can check if offsetParent = body for non visible elements.

Comment: i am seeing `getComputedStyle(element).display` having the value of `table` in some elements (for instance TABLE elements) whose ancestor is `display:none` making is essentially useless.

Comment: You may wish to add that `<body>` elements do not have offsetParent. Source 1: https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#dom-htmlelement-offsetparent ; Source 2: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html

Comment: Just a note on the window.getComputedStyle method, it returns a _live_ CSSStyleDeclaration object. So you only have to grab the style once, then can re-check the object if you have to perform the check multiple times.

Comment: Be sure to check if the element is visible by `style.visible === "hidden"`

Comment: offsetParent can be "undefined". So it's better to check `!!element.offsetParent === true` or just `!!element.offsetParent`

Comment: This solution will *not* work if the element or any of its ancestors has `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: The `element.offsetParent` together with `window.onload` handler worked in my case to check if the fallback node of an `<object>` is rendered or not. I managed to load a PDF viewer (pdf.js-dist), only when browser doesn't support native PDF view (e.g. browsing from smartphone).

Answer (score 171):

All the other solutions broke for some situation for me..

See the winning answer breaking at:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6CSCA2fe4Gqt4jCBP2wu?p=preview

Eventually, I decided that the best solution was `$(elem).is(':visible')` - however, this is not pure javascript. it is jquery..

so I peeked at their source and found what I wanted

```
jQuery.expr.filters.visible = function( elem ) {
    return !!( elem.offsetWidth || elem.offsetHeight || elem.getClientRects().length );
};
```

This is the source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css/hiddenVisibleSelectors.js

Comment: This will return `true` for an element with `visibility:hidden`

Comment: @YuvalA.: Yeah because the element is still visible. Setting a element to `visibility:hidden` shows no content anymore, but still takes the width and height of the element!

Comment: OP asked for a solution with no jQuery

Comment: For anyone looking for a version that also works with `visibility:hidden`, adding `&& window.getComputedStyle(elem).visibility !== "hidden"` to the end of this return line seems to work

Comment: @DougWilhelm That's why the source code is shown. The source code is pure javascript, since jQuery doesn't use other libraries at this place.

Comment: For me, a better solution was to use `&&` in the conditions like `(elem.offsetWidth && elem.offsetHeight && elem.getClientRects().length)` since if either the width or height is 0, then the element would not be visible to the user.

Answer (score 110):

If you're interested in visible by the user:

```
function isVisible(elem) {
    if (!(elem instanceof Element)) throw Error('DomUtil: elem is not an element.');
    const style = getComputedStyle(elem);
    if (style.display === 'none') return false;
    if (style.visibility !== 'visible') return false;
    if (style.opacity < 0.1) return false;
    if (elem.offsetWidth + elem.offsetHeight + elem.getBoundingClientRect().height +
        elem.getBoundingClientRect().width === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    const elemCenter   = {
        x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().left + elem.offsetWidth / 2,
        y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + elem.offsetHeight / 2
    };
    if (elemCenter.x < 0) return false;
    if (elemCenter.x > (document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.innerWidth)) return false;
    if (elemCenter.y < 0) return false;
    if (elemCenter.y > (document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight)) return false;
    let pointContainer = document.elementFromPoint(elemCenter.x, elemCenter.y);
    do {
        if (pointContainer === elem) return true;
    } while (pointContainer = pointContainer.parentNode);
    return false;
}
```

Tested on (using [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) terminology):

```
describe.only('visibility', function () {
    let div, visible, notVisible, inViewport, leftOfViewport, rightOfViewport, aboveViewport,
        belowViewport, notDisplayed, zeroOpacity, zIndex1, zIndex2;
    before(() => {
        div = document.createElement('div');
        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(div);
        div.appendChild(visible = document.createElement('div'));
        visible.style       = 'border: 1px solid black; margin: 5px; display: inline-block;';
        visible.textContent = 'visible';
        div.appendChild(inViewport = visible.cloneNode(false));
        inViewport.textContent = 'inViewport';
        div.appendChild(notDisplayed = visible.cloneNode(false));
        notDisplayed.style.display = 'none';
        notDisplayed.textContent   = 'notDisplayed';
        div.appendChild(notVisible = visible.cloneNode(false));
        notVisible.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        notVisible.textContent      = 'notVisible';
        div.appendChild(leftOfViewport = visible.cloneNode(false));
        leftOfViewport.style.position = 'absolute';
        leftOfViewport.style.right = '100000px';
        leftOfViewport.textContent = 'leftOfViewport';
        div.appendChild(rightOfViewport = leftOfViewport.cloneNode(false));
        rightOfViewport.style.right       = '0';
        rightOfViewport.style.left       = '100000px';
        rightOfViewport.textContent = 'rightOfViewport';
        div.appendChild(aboveViewport = leftOfViewport.cloneNode(false));
        aboveViewport.style.right       = '0';
        aboveViewport.style.bottom       = '100000px';
        aboveViewport.textContent = 'aboveViewport';
        div.appendChild(belowViewport = leftOfViewport.cloneNode(false));
        belowViewport.style.right       = '0';
        belowViewport.style.top       = '100000px';
        belowViewport.textContent = 'belowViewport';
        div.appendChild(zeroOpacity = visible.cloneNode(false));
        zeroOpacity.textContent   = 'zeroOpacity';
        zeroOpacity.style.opacity = '0';
        div.appendChild(zIndex1 = visible.cloneNode(false));
        zIndex1.textContent = 'zIndex1';
        zIndex1.style.position = 'absolute';
        zIndex1.style.left = zIndex1.style.top = zIndex1.style.width = zIndex1.style.height = '100px';
        zIndex1.style.zIndex = '1';
        div.appendChild(zIndex2 = zIndex1.cloneNode(false));
        zIndex2.textContent = 'zIndex2';
        zIndex2.style.left = zIndex2.style.top = '90px';
        zIndex2.style.width = zIndex2.style.height = '120px';
        zIndex2.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        zIndex2.style.zIndex = '2';
    });
    after(() => {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    });
    it('isVisible = true', () => {
        expect(isVisible(div)).to.be.true;
        expect(isVisible(visible)).to.be.true;
        expect(isVisible(inViewport)).to.be.true;
        expect(isVisible(zIndex2)).to.be.true;
    });
    it('isVisible = false', () => {
        expect(isVisible(notDisplayed)).to.be.false;
        expect(isVisible(notVisible)).to.be.false;
        expect(isVisible(document.createElement('div'))).to.be.false;
        expect(isVisible(zIndex1)).to.be.false;
        expect(isVisible(zeroOpacity)).to.be.false;
        expect(isVisible(leftOfViewport)).to.be.false;
        expect(isVisible(rightOfViewport)).to.be.false;
        expect(isVisible(aboveViewport)).to.be.false;
        expect(isVisible(belowViewport)).to.be.false;
    });
});
```

Comment: an edge case if the elem is positioned outside of the viewport, can be caught by "if (!pointContainer) return false;" checking the first pointContainer

Comment: If you want to check whether the user could possibly see it, you would have to use a `scrollIntoView` right?! This is quite expensive. Is there another clever way?

Comment: What about a case when overlapping element (to be precise: all overlapping elements) has opacity < 1?

Answer (score 58):

Use [the same code as jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c66d4700dcf98efccb04061d575e242d28741223/src/css/hiddenVisibleSelectors.js) does:

```
jQuery.expr.pseudos.visible = function( elem ) {
    return !!( elem.offsetWidth || elem.offsetHeight || elem.getClientRects().length );
};
```

So, in a function:

```
function isVisible(e) {
    return !!( e.offsetWidth || e.offsetHeight || e.getClientRects().length );
}
```

Works like a charm in my Win/IE10, Linux/Firefox.45, Linux/Chrome.52...

Many thanks to jQuery without jQuery!

Comment: Nice but doesn't cover elements being hidden by overflow.

Comment: nice but what why !! (double negation)?

Comment: To force the result as boolean. As `e.offsetWidth` is an integer, `!e.offsetWidth` will return `false` if `e.offsetWidth` is higher than zero (element is visible). So adding another `!` as in `!!e.offsetWidth` will return `true` if `e.offsetWidth` is higher than zero. It's a shorthand for `return e.offsetWidth > 0 ? true : false` or obviously `return e.offsetWidth > 0`.

Comment: So if I wanted a "isHidden" function instead, I would use a single `!` instead of `!!`?

Comment: @Jarad you're right :-) The double `!!` is used to force result to boolean. But as you want the opposite, only one is needed.

Comment: Why 50 votes? This is a copy of guy mograbi's answer from eight months earlier.

Answer (score 49):

[Chrome 105](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5163102852087808) (and Edge and Opera) and [Firefox 106](https://github.com/mozilla/standards-positions/issues/634) introduced [`Element.checkVisibility()`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_checkvisibility) which returns `true` if the element is visible, and `false` otherwise.

The function checks a variety of factors that would make an element invisible, including `display:none`, `visibility`, `content-visibility`, and `opacity`:

```js
let element = document.getElementById("myIcon");
let isVisible = element.checkVisibility({
    checkOpacity: true,      // Check CSS opacity property too
    checkVisibilityCSS: true // Check CSS visibility property too
});
```

**Sidenote**: `checkVisibility()` was previously called `isVisible()`. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7317#issuecomment-1170204212).
See [`checkVisibility()` specification draft here](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/cssom-view-1/#dom-element-checkvisibility).

Comment: The elegant solution that actually works. although browser support is very limited, a recommended solution.

https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_checkvisibility

Comment: It should be noted that even modern (16.3) versions of Safari do not support `checkVisibility`.

Comment: And it seems, as of early March 2023 that there isn't a polyfill

Comment: I wouldn't call "everything but safari" "very limited"

Comment: @stackers, your definition of "limited" is going to depend on your user base, not browser support. For any site with high iOS traffic "not supported in Safari" is also "very limited support".

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't check for "hidden" attribute...

Answer (score 46):

The accepted answer did not work for me.

### Year 2020 breakdown.

1. The `(elem.offsetParent !== null)` method works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome. In Chrome `position: fixed` will also make `offsetParent` return `null` even the element if visible in the page.

   User Phrogz conducted a large test (2,304 divs) on elements with varying properties to demonstrate the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639664/4481831 . **Run it with multiple browsers to see the differences.**

   Demo:

   ```js
   //different results in Chrome and Firefox
   console.log(document.querySelector('#hidden1').offsetParent); //null Chrome & Firefox
   console.log(document.querySelector('#fixed1').offsetParent); //null in Chrome, not null in Firefox
   ```

   ```html
       <div id="hidden1" style="display:none;"></div>
       <div id="fixed1" style="position:fixed;"></div>
   ```
2. The `(getComputedStyle(elem).display !== 'none')` does not work because the element can be invisible because one of the parents display property is set to none, `getComputedStyle` will not catch that.

   Demo:

   ```js
   var child1 = document.querySelector('#child1');
   console.log(getComputedStyle(child1).display);
   //child will show "block" instead of "none"
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="parent1" style="display:none;">
     <div id="child1" style="display:block"></div>
   </div>
   ```
3. The `(elem.clientHeight !== 0)`. This method is not influenced by `position: fixed` and it also check if element parents are not-visible. But it has problems with simple elements that do not have a css layout and inline elements, [see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438642/clientwidth-and-clientheight-report-zero-while-getboundingclientrect-is-correct)

   Demo:

   ```js
   console.log(document.querySelector('#inline1').clientHeight); //zero
   console.log(document.querySelector('#div1').clientHeight); //not zero
   console.log(document.querySelector('#span1').clientHeight); //zero
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="inline1" style="display:inline">test1 inline</div>
   <div id="div1">test2 div</div>
   <span id="span1">test3 span</span>
   ```
4. The `(elem.getClientRects().length !== 0)` may seem to solve the problems of the previous 3 methods. However it has problems with elements that use CSS tricks (other then `display: none`) to hide in the page.

   Demo

   ```js
   console.log(document.querySelector('#notvisible1').getClientRects().length);
   console.log(document.querySelector('#notvisible1').clientHeight);
   console.log(document.querySelector('#notvisible2').getClientRects().length);
   console.log(document.querySelector('#notvisible2').clientHeight);
   console.log(document.querySelector('#notvisible3').getClientRects().length);
   console.log(document.querySelector('#notvisible3').clientHeight);
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="notvisible1" style="height:0; overflow:hidden; background-color:red;">not visible 1</div>

   <div id="notvisible2" style="visibility:hidden; background-color:yellow;">not visible 2</div>

   <div id="notvisible3" style="opacity:0; background-color:blue;">not visible 3</div>
   ```

### Conclusion.

So what I have showed you is that no method is perfect. To make a proper visibility check, you must use a combination of the last 3 methods.

Comment: In Chrome 88.0.4324.104 the first result give me null, null.

Comment: I updated your great answer with a JS snippet of your solution!

Comment: Not working when [parent is hidden](https://pastebin.com/XHHAwwv0)

Comment: @Byzod the function was added by a moderator. I will remove it for my answer to not be downvoted. Like I said in the answer method 4 should be enough for most cases. Method 2 & 3 should only be used if you want to check against CSS visibility tricks to hide elements in the page (I have given 3 examples of invisibility CSS tricks in the method 4). For example getComputedStyle can be used to check for opacity>0.

Comment: @Byzod I have made an example with a function https://jsfiddle.net/79uzoj4v/ . Others: please do not edit my answer to add a function. The scope of the answer was to make a breakdown of previous discussed solutions.

Answer (score 44):

**This may help :**
Hide the element by positioning it on far most left position and then check the offsetLeft property. If you want to use jQuery you can simply check the [*:visible*](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector and get the visibility state of the element.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="myDiv">Hello</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
<!-- for javaScript-->
#myDiv{
   position:absolute;
   left : -2000px;
}

<!-- for jQuery -->
#myDiv{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

**javaScript :**

```
var myStyle = document.getElementById("myDiv").offsetLeft;

if(myStyle < 0){
     alert("Div is hidden!!");
}
```

**jQuery :**

```
if(  $("#MyElement").is(":visible") == true )
{  
     alert("Div is visible!!");        
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/Nr99p/)

Comment: The OP requests a no-jQuery answer.

Comment: It was edited later i guess. When I answered it wasn't mentioned in the thread.

Comment: @StephenQuan, I've updated the answer with both jQuery and javaScript solution.

Comment: for the jQuery example, shouldn't the alert say "Div is visible?"

Comment: I wouldn't want to conclude an element is entirely hidden just because its offsetLeft is less than 0: what if it's only a small number of pixels less than 0 and its right-hand part is visible? (I agree this would seem like a silly design, but you never know with web designers these days.) It's probably better to add the width to offsetLeft and see if the result is still less than 0. Just in case.

Comment: I am glad there is multiple solutions despite asking for no-jquery. Future readers with or without jquery like me get also get an answer here and choose :D

Comment: A screen reader will still pick up content that is moved visually off-screen. It is, in fact, an accepted method of handling screen reader only content.

Comment: `HTMLElement.offsetHeight` would be a better check of visibility.

Answer (score 34):

## 2021 solution

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) an interaction observer asynchronously observe changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor element or with a top-level document's viewport. This means every time the element intersects with the viewport the interaction observer will trigger.

As of 2021, all the current browser supports intersection observer except IE.

### Implementation

```js
const el = document.getElementById("your-target-element");
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting){
         // el is visible
    } else {
         // el is not visible
    }
});

observer.observe(el); // Asynchronous call
```

The handler will fire when initially created. And then it will fire every time that it becomes slightly visible or becomes completely *not* visible. An element is deemed to be not-visible when it's not actually visible within the viewport. So if you scroll down and element goes off the screen, then the observer will trigger and the `// el is not visible` code will be triggered - even though the element is still "displayed" (i.e. doesn't have `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`). What matters is whether there are any pixels of the element that are *actually visible within the viewport*.

Comment: Important note: IntersectionObserver callback is asynchronous => you won't get result immediately after you call `observer.observe(el)`;

Comment: Does this only trigger when a change in visibility is made?

Comment: IE, will it fire when initially created?

Comment: Answer to Mattwmaster58's question: Yes, it will fire when initially created. And then it will fire every time that it becomes slightly visible or becomes completely *not* visible. An element is counted as not being visible when it's not actually displayed on the screen. So if you scroll down and element goes off the screen, then the observer will trigger and the `// el is not visible` code will be triggered. I'll add this comment to the answer.

Comment: I used this with a el.scrollIntoView - it caused major flickering, but realized I forgot to add observer.disconnect() if the element was visible. As IE is dead, this solution is perfect for my needs. Thanks +1

Answer (score 23):

Combining a couple answers above:

```
function isVisible (ele) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(ele);
    return  style.width !== "0" &&
    style.height !== "0" &&
    style.opacity !== "0" &&
    style.display!=='none' &&
    style.visibility!== 'hidden';
}
```

Like AlexZ said, this may be slower than some of your other options if you know more specifically what you're looking for, but this should catch all of the main ways elements are hidden.

But, it also depends what counts as visible for you. Just for example, a div's height can be set to 0px but the contents still visible depending on the overflow properties. Or a div's contents could be made the same color as the background so it is not visible to users but still rendered on the page. Or a div could be moved off screen or hidden behind other divs, or it's contents could be non-visible but the border still visible. To a certain extent "visible" is a subjective term.

Comment: Nice, but style.opacity, style.height and style.width return a string so it won't work with !==

Comment: Another way that an element could be hidden via style is that it's color could match the background color, or it's z-index could be lower than other elements.

Comment: adding `display:none` to this would be great. A proper working solution!

Answer (score 9):

I've got a more performant solution compared to [AlexZ's getComputedStyle() solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom/21696585#21696585) when one has position 'fixed' elements, if one is willing to ignore some edge cases (check comments):

```
function isVisible(el) {
    /* offsetParent would be null if display 'none' is set.
       However Chrome, IE and MS Edge returns offsetParent as null for elements
       with CSS position 'fixed'. So check whether the dimensions are zero.

       This check would be inaccurate if position is 'fixed' AND dimensions were
       intentionally set to zero. But..it is good enough for most cases.*/
    return Boolean(el.offsetParent || el.offsetWidth || el.offsetHeight);
}
```

Side note: Strictly speaking, "visibility" needs to be defined first. In my case, I am considering an element visible as long as I can run all DOM methods/properties on it without problems (even if opacity is 0 or CSS visibility property is 'hidden' etc).

Answer (score 8):

If element is regular visible (display:block and visibillity:visible), but some parent container is hidden, then we can use **clientWidth** and **clientHeight** for check that.

```
function isVisible (ele) {
  return  ele.clientWidth !== 0 &&
    ele.clientHeight !== 0 &&
    (ele.style.opacity !== '' ? parseFloat(ele.style.opacity) > 0 : true);
}
```

[Plunker (click here)](http://plnkr.co/edit/RoSIt2)

Comment: `ele.style.visibility !== 'hidden'` is redundant here.  In that case, clientWidth and clientHeight will be 0.

Comment: Opacity check needs to be coerced to number, because `style` values are all strings. Eg, `parseFloat(ele.style.opacity) < 0.1`

Answer (score 7):

A little addition to ohad navon's answer.

If the center of the element belongs to the another element we won't find it.

So to make sure that one of the points of the element is found to be visible

```
function isElementVisible(elem) {
    if (!(elem instanceof Element)) throw Error('DomUtil: elem is not an element.');
    const style = getComputedStyle(elem);
    if (style.display === 'none') return false;
    if (style.visibility !== 'visible') return false;
    if (style.opacity === 0) return false;
    if (elem.offsetWidth + elem.offsetHeight + elem.getBoundingClientRect().height +
        elem.getBoundingClientRect().width === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    var elementPoints = {
        'center': {
            x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().left + elem.offsetWidth / 2,
            y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + elem.offsetHeight / 2
        },
        'top-left': {
            x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().left,
            y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().top
        },
        'top-right': {
            x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().right,
            y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().top
        },
        'bottom-left': {
            x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().left,
            y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
        },
        'bottom-right': {
            x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().right,
            y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
        }
    }

    for(index in elementPoints) {
        var point = elementPoints[index];
        if (point.x < 0) return false;
        if (point.x > (document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.innerWidth)) return false;
        if (point.y < 0) return false;
        if (point.y > (document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight)) return false;
        let pointContainer = document.elementFromPoint(point.x, point.y);
        if (pointContainer !== null) {
            do {
                if (pointContainer === elem) return true;
            } while (pointContainer = pointContainer.parentNode);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for the reference it should be noted that `getBoundingClientRect()` can work in certain cases.

For example, a simple check that the element is hidden using `display: none` could look somewhat like this:

```
var box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var visible = box.width && box.height;
```

This is also handy because it also covers zero-width, zero-height and `position: fixed` cases. However, it shall not report elements hidden with `opacity: 0` or `visibility: hidden` (but neither would `offsetParent`).

Comment: Best answer for me... simple and effective. And no single upvote after 3 years! Goes on to show the worth of “crowd wisdom”. My version: `var isVisible = el => (r => r.width && r.height)(el.getBoundingClientRect());`. Then I can filter arrays of elements in the following way: `$$(sel).filter(isVisible)`.

Comment: I find it the simplest solution https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: This does not work when visible to the user.... if you scroll away it will remain true

Comment: @RayFoss you do understand that there are various definitions to "visible", right? :)

Just to make it clear "Visible in DOM" or "Visible on screen" or "Visible in viewport" or "Visible within the container with scrollbars" — all of those mean different things and implementations. Also, how visible is the element? Is it only visible when all of its pixels are rendered? (what about transforms?) Or, otherwise, is it visible if only its "conceptually transparent" padding is currently on screen?

To summarize, I think the definition will depend a lot about your specific use case.

Answer (score 6):

So what I found is the most feasible method:

```
function visible(elm) {
  if(!elm.offsetHeight && !elm.offsetWidth) { return false; }
  if(getComputedStyle(elm).visibility === 'hidden') { return false; }
  return true;
}
```

This is build on these facts:

- A `display: none` element (even a nested one) doesn't have a width nor height.
- `visiblity` is `hidden` even for nested elements.

So no need for testing `offsetParent` or looping up in the DOM tree to test which parent has `visibility: hidden`. This should work even in IE 9.

You could argue if `opacity: 0` and collapsed elements (has a width but no height - or visa versa) is not really visible either. But then again they are not per say hidden.

Answer (score 4):

If we're just collecting basic ways of detecting visibility, let me not forget:

```
opacity > 0.01; // probably more like .1 to actually be visible, but YMMV
```

And as to how to obtain attributes:

```
element.getAttribute(attributename);
```

So, in your example:

```
document.getElementById('snDealsPanel').getAttribute('visibility');
```

But wha? It doesn't work here. Look closer and you'll find that visibility is being updated not as an attribute on the element, but using the `style` property. This is one of many problems with trying to do what you're doing. Among others: you can't guarantee that there's actually something to see in an element, just because its visibility, display, and opacity all have the correct values. It still might lack content, or it might lack a height and width. Another object might obscure it. For more detail, a quick Google search reveals [this](http://useallfive.com/thoughts/javascript-tool-detect-if-a-dom-element-is-truly-visible/), and even includes a library to try solving the problem. (YMMV)

Check out the following, which are possible duplicates of this question, with excellent answers, including some insight from the mighty John Resig. However, your specific use-case is slightly different from the standard one, so I'll refrain from flagging:

- [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)
- [How to check if an element is really visible with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704758/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-really-visible-with-javascript)

(EDIT: OP SAYS HE'S SCRAPING PAGES, NOT CREATING THEM, SO BELOW ISN'T APPLICABLE)
A better option? Bind the visibility of elements to model properties and always make visibility contingent on that model, much as Angular does with ng-show. You can do that using any tool you want: Angular, plain JS, whatever. Better still, you can change the DOM implementation over time, but you'll always be able to read state from the model, instead of the DOM. Reading your truth from the DOM is Bad. And slow. Much better to check the model, and trust in your implementation to ensure that the DOM state reflects the model. (And use automated testing to confirm that assumption.)

Comment: I am parsing sites, this is not for my own site... :)

Answer (score 4):

Improving on @Guy Messika's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47647393/640989), breaking and returning false if the center point' X is < 0 is wrong as the element right side may go into the view. here's a fix:

```
private isVisible(elem) {
    const style = getComputedStyle(elem);

    if (style.display === 'none') return false;
    if (style.visibility !== 'visible') return false;
    if ((style.opacity as any) === 0) return false;

    if (
        elem.offsetWidth +
        elem.offsetHeight +
        elem.getBoundingClientRect().height +
        elem.getBoundingClientRect().width === 0
    ) return false;

    const elementPoints = {
        center: {
            x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().left + elem.offsetWidth / 2,
            y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + elem.offsetHeight / 2,
        },
        topLeft: {
            x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().left,
            y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().top,
        },
        topRight: {
            x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().right,
            y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().top,
        },
        bottomLeft: {
            x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().left,
            y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
        },
        bottomRight: {
            x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().right,
            y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
        },
    };

    const docWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.innerWidth;
    const docHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight;

    if (elementPoints.topLeft.x > docWidth) return false;
    if (elementPoints.topLeft.y > docHeight) return false;
    if (elementPoints.bottomRight.x < 0) return false;
    if (elementPoints.bottomRight.y < 0) return false;

    for (let index in elementPoints) {
        const point = elementPoints[index];
        let pointContainer = document.elementFromPoint(point.x, point.y);
        if (pointContainer !== null) {
            do {
                if (pointContainer === elem) return true;
            } while (pointContainer = pointContainer.parentNode);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on everyone's great answers, here is [the implementation](https://github.com/mozilla/fathom/blob/master/fathom/utilsForFrontend.mjs#L471) that was used in the Mozilla Fathom project:

```js
/**
 * Yield an element and each of its ancestors.
 */
export function *ancestors(element) {
    yield element;
    let parent;
    while ((parent = element.parentNode) !== null && parent.nodeType === parent.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        yield parent;
        element = parent;
    }
}

/**
 * Return whether an element is practically visible, considering things like 0
 * size or opacity, ``visibility: hidden`` and ``overflow: hidden``.
 *
 * Merely being scrolled off the page in either horizontally or vertically
 * doesn't count as invisible; the result of this function is meant to be
 * independent of viewport size.
 *
 * @throws {Error} The element (or perhaps one of its ancestors) is not in a
 *     window, so we can't find the `getComputedStyle()` routine to call. That
 *     routine is the source of most of the information we use, so you should
 *     pick a different strategy for non-window contexts.
 */
export function isVisible(fnodeOrElement) {
    // This could be 5x more efficient if https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4122 happens.
    const element = toDomElement(fnodeOrElement);
    const elementWindow = windowForElement(element);
    const elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const elementStyle = elementWindow.getComputedStyle(element);
    // Alternative to reading ``display: none`` due to Bug 1381071.
    if (elementRect.width === 0 && elementRect.height === 0 && elementStyle.overflow !== 'hidden') {
        return false;
    }
    if (elementStyle.visibility === 'hidden') {
        return false;
    }
    // Check if the element is irrevocably off-screen:
    if (elementRect.x + elementRect.width < 0 ||
        elementRect.y + elementRect.height < 0
    ) {
        return false;
    }
    for (const ancestor of ancestors(element)) {
        const isElement = ancestor === element;
        const style = isElement ? elementStyle : elementWindow.getComputedStyle(ancestor);
        if (style.opacity === '0') {
            return false;
        }
        if (style.display === 'contents') {
            // ``display: contents`` elements have no box themselves, but children are
            // still rendered.
            continue;
        }
        const rect = isElement ? elementRect : ancestor.getBoundingClientRect();
        if ((rect.width === 0 || rect.height === 0) && elementStyle.overflow === 'hidden') {
            // Zero-sized ancestors don’t make descendants hidden unless the descendant
            // has ``overflow: hidden``.
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It checks on every parent's opacity, display, and rectangle.

Comment: Note that this code also requires [toDomElement](https://github.com/mozilla/fathom/blob/2b2c84e/fathom/utilsForFrontend.mjs#L398-L400), [isDomElement](https://github.com/mozilla/fathom/blob/2b2c84e/fathom/utilsForFrontend.mjs#L603-L605) and [windowForElement](https://github.com/mozilla/fathom/blob/2b2c84e/fathom/utilsForFrontend.mjs#L626-L637) to work. But in any case, it fails in the test I'm doing (I get `false` for an element that's visible and for one that's invisible).

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery code from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js has an isHidden param

```
var isHidden = function( elem, el ) {
    // isHidden might be called from jQuery#filter function;
    // in that case, element will be second argument
    elem = el || elem;
    return jQuery.css( elem, "display" ) === "none" || !jQuery.contains( elem.ownerDocument, elem );
};
```

So it looks like there is an extra check related to the owner document

I wonder if this really catches the following cases:

1. Elements hidden behind other elements based on zIndex
2. Elements with transparency full making them invisible
3. Elements positioned off screen (ie left: -1000px)
4. Elements with visibility:hidden
5. Elements with display:none
6. Elements with no visible text or sub elements
7. Elements with height or width set to 0

Answer (score 2):

```
let element = document.getElementById('element');
let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

if(rect.top == 0 && 
  rect.bottom == 0 && 
  rect.left == 0 && 
  rect.right == 0 && 
  rect.width == 0 && 
  rect.height == 0 && 
  rect.x == 0 && 
  rect.y == 0)
{
  alert('hidden');
}
else
{
  alert('visible');
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. For future readers it's far more interesting to see explained *why* this answers the question. Also, you need to explain even more when you answer an old, already well answered question.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const isVisible = (selector) => {
  let selectedElement
  let topElement
  let selectedData
  
  selectedElement = document.querySelector(selector)
  
  if (!selectedElement) {
    return false
  }
  
  selectedData = selectedElement.getBoundingClientRect()
  if (!selectedData || !Object.keys(selectedData)) {
    return false
  }
  
  if (!(selectedData.width > 0) || !(selectedData.height > 0)) {
    return false
  }
  
  topElement = document.elementFromPoint(selectedData.top, selectedData.left)
  
  if (selectedElement !== topElement) {
    return false
  }
  
  return true
}

const output = document.querySelector('.text')
output.innerHTML = '.x element is visible: ' + isVisible('.x')
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}

.y {
  background: red;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="x block"></div>
<div class="y block"></div>
```

Comment: This may not work if the element is partially obscured (on its top-left corner) by another overlapping element

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (pure vanilla JS) function that performs an extensive number of checks, ensuring that a given element is visible to the user:

```
function isVisible(element) {
    // Check if the element is null or undefined
    if (!element) return false;

    // Get the element's bounding client rect
    const boundingRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Check if the element has a positive width and height
    if (boundingRect.width <= 0 || boundingRect.height <= 0) return false;

    // Check if the element's top and left values are within the viewport
    const top = boundingRect.top;
    const left = boundingRect.left;
    const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    if (top > viewportHeight || left > viewportWidth) return false;

    // Check if the element's right and bottom values are within the viewport
    const right = boundingRect.right;
    const bottom = boundingRect.bottom;
    if (right < 0 || bottom < 0) return false;

    // Check if the element is hidden by the overflow property
    const parentNode = element.parentNode;
    if (parentNode && getComputedStyle(parentNode).overflow === 'hidden') {
        const parentRect = parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (top < parentRect.top || bottom > parentRect.bottom || left < parentRect.left || right > parentRect.right) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    const elementComputedStyle = getComputedStyle(element);

    // Check if the element has a z-index of less than 0
    const zIndex = elementComputedStyle.zIndex;
    if (zIndex < 0) return false;

    // Check if the element has a display value of 'none' or an opacity of 0
    const display = elementComputedStyle.display;
    const opacity = elementComputedStyle.opacity;
    if (display === 'none' || opacity === '0') return false;

    // Check if the element is hidden by an ancestor element with a display value of 'none' or an opacity of 0
    let ancestorElement = element.parentElement;
    while (ancestorElement) {
        const ancestorComputedStyle = getComputedStyle(ancestorElement);
        const ancestorDisplay = ancestorComputedStyle.display;
        const ancestorOpacity = ancestorComputedStyle.opacity;
        if (ancestorDisplay === 'none' || ancestorOpacity === '0') return false;
        ancestorElement = ancestorElement.parentElement;
    }

    // Initialize a variable to keep track of whether the element is obscured by another element
    let obscured = false;

    // Check if the element is obscured by another element according to its position
    if (elementComputedStyle.position === 'absolute' || elementComputedStyle.position === 'fixed' ||
        elementComputedStyle.position === 'relative' || elementComputedStyle.position === 'sticky' ||
        elementComputedStyle.position === 'static') {
        let siblingElement = element.nextElementSibling;
        while (siblingElement) {
            if (siblingElement.getBoundingClientRect().top > boundingRect.bottom || siblingElement.getBoundingClientRect().left > boundingRect.right) {
                break;
            }
            if (siblingElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > boundingRect.top && siblingElement.getBoundingClientRect().right > boundingRect.left) {
                obscured = true;
                break;
            }
            siblingElement = siblingElement.nextElementSibling;
        }
        if (obscured) return false;
    }

    // If all checks have passed, the element is visible
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works with zero height elements:

```
const divElement = document.getElementById('yourDivId'); // Replace 'yourDivId' with the actual ID of your div

const rect = divElement.getBoundingClientRect();
const isVisible = rect.bottom > 0 && rect.top < window.innerHeight;

if (isVisible) {
    console.log('The div is visible.'); // Or partially visible
} else {
    console.log('The div is not visible.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are scraping sites, one very inefficient method which worked for me was highlighting whatever element, and screenshotting, and then checking if the screenshot has changed.

```
//Screenshot

function makeSelected(element){
    let range = new Range()
    range.selectNode(element)
    let selection = window.getSelection()
    selection.removeAllRanges()
    selection.addRange(range)
}
// screenshot again and check for diff
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the code I wrote to find the only visible among a few similar elements, and return the value of its "class" attribute without jQuery:

```
  // Build a NodeList:
  var nl = document.querySelectorAll('.myCssSelector');

  // convert it to array:
  var myArray = [];for(var i = nl.length; i--; myArray.unshift(nl[i]));

  // now find the visible (= with offsetWidth more than 0) item:
  for (i =0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    var curEl = myArray[i];
    if (curEl.offsetWidth !== 0){
      return curEl.getAttribute("class");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a way to determine it for all css properties including visibility:

html:

```
<div id="element">div content</div>
```

css:

```
#element
{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
 if(element.style.visibility == 'hidden'){
alert('hidden');
}
else
{
alert('visible');
}
```

It works for any css property and is very versatile and reliable.

Comment: [element.style.display == "none"] is working for me

Answer (score -2):

This is what I did:

**HTML & CSS: Made the element hidden by default**

```
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

<p id="demo" style ="visibility: hidden;">Hello World</p> 

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript: Added a code to check whether the visibility is hidden or not:**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   if ( document.getElementById("demo").style.visibility === "hidden"){
   document.getElementById("demo").style.visibility = "visible";
   }
   else document.getElementById("demo").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

In case you encountered text nodes, try this:

```
// Where n a node you'd like to test for visibility
function isHidden(n) {
    if(n.nodeType==3){
        el = n.parentElement;
    }else{
        el = n;
    }
     
    return (el.offsetParent === null)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

2023 Solution :)

with jquery plugin

```
$.fn.isvisible = function(e) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle($(this)[0]);
    return (style.display != 'none')
}
alert($('.classname').isvisible())
```

Comment: This doesn't account for parent elements with display none, nor for visibility; It uses jQuery despite the question explicitly asking not to (plus there is no need to use it for your code anyway) and lastly I'd say that `$(this)[0]` goes some extra unneeded steps, but that's just details

Answer (score -3):

There are many situations where this will not necessarily work, however in my case I'm using this and it works fine for what I need. So if you are looking for a basic solution (Which does not cover every eventuality) it 'might' be helpful to you, if this simple solution suits your particular need.

```
var element= document.getElementById('elementId');

if (element.style.display == "block"){

<!-- element is visible -->

} else {

<!-- element is hidden-->

}
```

Comment: There are so many situations where this obviously won't work, since `display: block` is not the only style an element can have and still be visible.

Answer (score -8):

```
var visible = document.getElementById("yourelementID's");
 if (visible){
          // make events
 } else
 {
   //other events
 }
```

Comment: This does not check if an element is visible. It checks if it is in the DOM. It could be in the DOM and hidden, not displayed, covered up by another element, or positioned outside the viewport.

Comment: Quentin
 r u test it? it is work for me.

Comment: I didn't need to test it since the flaws are huge and obvious, but here is a demo of one way it fails: https://jsbin.com/xixakiqafu/1/edit?html,css,js,output