# Detect if element is hidden from user because of parent hidden attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In pure javascript/DOM is there a way to know if an element is hidden?  As in I have something like this:

```
    <div id="creator" hiddden="hidden">
      <dl>
        <dt> <label for="creator">Creator:</label> </dt>
        <dd>
           <input type="text" name="creator"/>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
```

So from acquiring the form element only, is it possible to find if its hidden because an ancestor has a hidden attribute?

Many thanks

Comment: Try valid markup, and we'll try to help. Tip : computedStyle ?

Comment: First of all it should be `hidden`, suppose it is a typo, isn't it ?!

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look how jQuery [does it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css/hiddenVisibleSelectors.js):

```
jQuery.expr.filters.hidden = function( elem ) {
    // Support: Opera <= 12.12
    // Opera reports offsetWidths and offsetHeights less than zero on some elements
    return elem.offsetWidth <= 0 && elem.offsetHeight <= 0;
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xJ2Dr/

Answer (score -1):

`Element.offsetParent==null`

> then element is hidden