# search an element in a repeater containing specific text using protractor

Tags: protractor

How could I search an element from a repeater containing a specific text ?

I tried things like that :

```
element(by.repeater('item in array')).all(by.cssContainingText('.xyz','my item title')); // only gets the first element
```

I could search by myself using `.then` after `element.all` but I'm wondering if it exists something simpler like `cssContainingText` but for repeaters :

```
element(by.repeaterContainingText('item in array','my item title'))
```

or a element chaining like that :

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in array')).element(by.cssContainingText('.xyz','my item title'));
```

A solution with filter (but very slow)

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in array')).filter(function(elem){
    return elem.getText().then(function(text){
        return text.indexOf('my item title') > -1;
    });
}).then(function(filteredElements) {
    return filteredElements[0];
})
```

Comment: please consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protractor allows adding locators..  I am using the following implementation (pure javascript) successfully in a project with 20 tests or so.

Here is a solution using lodash and jquery. 
Below there is also one in pure javascript.

https://gist.github.com/GuyMograbi/7a5f5e580bcf8d7da58a

```
by.addLocator('text',

/**
 *
 * @param {string} text - will be lowercased
 * @param {string} selector - to get list of children
 * @param {null|object} parent - protractor will provide this..
 */
function(text, selector, parent) {
    return _.filter($(parent || 'body').find(selector), function(e){
        return $(e).is(':visible') && $(e).text().toLowerCase().trim() === text.toLowerCase().trim();
    });
});
```

and use it with

```
return $('table').all(by.text('my text', 'tr')).first().getText().then(function(text){...})
```

or

```
return element(by.text('my text', 'tr')).getText().then(function(text){...})
```

## Don't forget the following about protractor and locators

I just spent 2 hours breaking my brains as to why my locator does not work. please remember the following:

- protractor 'ignores' hidden elements, however your locator does not do so by default.. so if you write a custom locator, in order for it to work as expected in angular you must filter out hidden elements
- if you need to debug, I found it most useful using `getOuterHtml().then..`

## Pure JavaScript

This is how the same will look without jquery and lodash

```
by.addLocator('text',

/**
 *
 * @param text - will be lowercased
 * @param selector - to get list of children
 * @param parent - protractor will provide this..
 */
function(text, selector, _parent) {

    return Array.prototype.filter.call( (_parent || document).querySelectorAll(selector), function(e){
        return e && !!(e.offsetWidth || e.offsetHeight || e.getClientRects().length) && e.textContent && e.textContent.toLowerCase().trim() === text.toLowerCase().trim();

    });
});
```

- - the `isVisible` part was eventually taken from jquery sources. see answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33456469/1068746

## Important note - or - why this should be the right answer

Using `filter` you get a promise. using this solution you get an element. So instead of having a `getByText(..).then(function(e){  e.click() })` you will have `getByText(...).click()` - sweeet!

## Limitations and possible enhancements

in your case, the repeater locator cannot be used which is a bummer, unless you modify the location instead of `text` to be `textInRepeater` and then have `'[ng-repeat=' + repeater + ']'` somehow added in the code.

Another thing you might want to enhance which is very useful. 
Sometime you want to get an element which CONTAINS text, or possibly contains a child with text, but you actually want to select the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can chain elements in Protractor.

```
element(locator1).element(locator2);
```

[protractor-Locators.md](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/fcd973b8f8b0164bd44c4438905bf3e54b2815bc/docs/locators.md)

Comment: I think element(locator1).element(locator2); applies when locator1 points to a single element, not an array of elements.

Comment: Right so element.all(locator1).element(locator2);

Answer (score -1):

I know you likely don't need the answer anymore but I though I would update in case someone else is having this same issue.  You can use

```
element(by.linkText('.xyz'));
```

Comment: there's no such locator in API : http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy

Comment: actually there is via the exposed webdriver API:
http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.linkText