# Quickly get class attribute of every WebElement with Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking to get the class attribute of every `WebElement` on the page quickly with selenium. Currently, I'm doing the following:

```
allElements = new ArrayList<WebElement>(m_webDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*")));

for (WebElement element : allElements) {
    String className = element.getAttribute("class");
}
```

This process is incredibly slow, taking upwards of thirty seconds on a page with 500 elements. I've tried parallelizing the `getAttribute` call, which is the slowest part of the method, but there was no speed increase. This leads me to believe that every call to `getAttribute` is fetching information instead of storing it locally.

Is there a faster or parallelizable way to do this?

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? Doing something like this Selenium is going to be incredibly inefficient, as you have observed.

Comment: I need a way to differentiate every element on the page (using a combination of class and location), so that I know if an element is added after a click or other interaction occurs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, *you cannot make selenium send batch `getAttribute()` calls for multiple elements.* Here is a similar problem I've looked into - it is about making `isDisplayed()` work for multiple elements without making JSON Wire protocol requests for every element in a list:

- [How can Selenium batch many isElementDisplayed calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221463/how-can-selenium-batch-many-iselementdisplayed-calls)

But, as opposed to this `isDisplayed()` problem, here we can execute javascript and reliably get the class attribute values for every element on a page, something like this to get you started:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("var result = []; " +
"var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); " +
"for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) { " +
"    result.push({'tag': all[i].tagName, 'class': all[i].getAttribute('class')}); " +
"} " +
" return result; ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple and use an XPath instead of a complex snip of Javascript:

```
// get all elements where class attribute is not null
List<WebElement> allElements = m_webDriver.findElements(
  By.xpath(".//*[@class and not(ancestor::div[contains(@style,'display:none')])]")
);

for (WebElement element : allElements) {
    String className = element.getAttribute("class");
}
```