# Calculate content height on Typescript file dynamicaly

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Can you tell me how to get the `height` of this `div` content?

i.e. I need it to calculate the dynamic heigh of the content

[image]

***code***

`.html`

```
<div class="margin-top-47 margin-horizontal-10" #hello>
//content here
</div>
```

I have tried like so. But no luck yet. Any clue, please?

`.ts`

```
@ViewChild('hello', { static: false }) hello: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   
    const xx = this.hello.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
   
    const contentHeight = xx.clientHeight;//it shows 0

    //const contentHeight = xx.scrollHeight;//it shows 0 too.
    
  }
```

`console.log` shows like so:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the div in question and its content is fully rendered when `ngAfterViewInit` gets called?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Yes, please see the update.

Comment: Did you try with `getBoundingClientRect()` ?. [More details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: Is this useful ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438642/clientwidth-and-clientheight-report-zero-while-getboundingclientrect-is-correct

Comment: @ThierryFalvo It shows like so: `bottom: 0
height: 0
left: 0
right: 0
top: 0
width: 0
x: 0
y: 0`

Comment: See that you use `{static:false}` **only** if your div is always visible (if it's not under a *ngIf). Check also if you has another variable that was called "hello"

Comment: NOTE: If you only want to change the heigth of one dive you can use directly in .html some like: `[style.height.px]="hello.clientHeight"`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out....

```
@ViewChild('hello', { static: false }) hello: ElementRef|any;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   
    const xx = this.hello.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
   
    const contentHeight = xx.clientHeight;
    console.log(contentHeight);


    
  }
```

check this Html src

[image]

check the log

[image]

Comment: Any reason why that one is not working with my code? Are you using Ionic/Angular or?

Comment: No not with ionic is simple angular 13.

Comment: Put your code Online on stackblitz And send me your Live url  . Then i hope I will  help you.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Ionic [Sheet modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#sheet-modal) component here. It requires giving a `500ms` delay as shown below to give the height.

.html

```
<div class="margin-top-47 margin-horizontal-10" #sheetModalContent >
 //content here
</div>
```

*.ts*

```
@ViewChild('sheetModalContent ', { static: false }) sheetModalContent : ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const sheetModalContent = this.sheetModalContent.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
      const sheetModalContentHeight = sheetModalContent.scrollHeight;
      console.log(`sheetModalContentHeight`, sheetModalContentHeight);//438
    }, 500);
  }
```