# How to get notified when an element is made visible on the page?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

It's clear to me how to check if an element is visible on the page, by using the functions explained [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom).

```
//Where el is the DOM element you'd like to test for visibility
function isHidden(el) {
    return (el.offsetParent === null)
}
```

Or

```
//Where el is the DOM element you'd like to test for visibility
function isHidden(el) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    return (style.display === 'none')
}
```

But to avoid pooling for the `isHidden(el)` function, I'd like to be notified when a given element is made visible in the DOM (with pure JS, no jQuery or other frameworks).

In theory [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) could be used, but I need a solution for IE10+ browsers.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing you have some other javascript that toggles visibility of DOM elements?  Is there a reason not to have that same toggleing function execute the code you want to run?

Comment: @AdamKonieska I have that scenario but not only that. I have a case where the visibility is toggled on a CSS animation, and one where the visibility is toggled by a CSS media query. I'm seeking a single way to be notified when an element is made visible, to cover all the cases when this could happen, not only by toggling via javascript.