# Finding only visible elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I'm working on coverting a JQuery project to pure JavaScript and I'm stuck with the following bit of code.

```
$(".element-has-class:visible")
```

I thought perhaps something along these lines might work to catch all visible element (in the case of my project list items) but I've had no luck:

```
function functionName (){
  var elementsOnShow = document.getElementsByClassName('element-has-class').find(isVisible);
}

function isVisible(element) {
  return element.style.display === 'block';
}
```

(`block` has been set in the CSS). Is there anyway to get all visible elements within one variable?

Comment: And you're not getting any errors, for instance "`NodeList.find` is not a funtion" or something similar

Comment: Check [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert your nodeList to an Array ([read more about it here](https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array)), which will allow you to use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the visible elements:

```
function functionName (){
  var myNodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('element-has-class'),
      myArray = [].slice.call(myNodeList),
      elementsOnShow = myArray.filter(isVisible);
}

function isVisible(element) {
  return element.offsetWidth > 0
      || element.offsetHeight > 0
      || element.getClientRects().length > 0;
}
```

The `isVisible` function you see above is extracted from jQuery 2.2.4's source code (version 3.X.X is not compatible with IE 8 and below).

Comment: I would like to add that if the style has been set through classes, use `getComputedStyle().display` to also factor those in.

Comment: According to https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/  - 'Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.' So I don't think checking display block will provide the exact behavior as :visible

Comment: @JithuPRajan Alright, I found it in jQuery's source code. See changes

Comment: Thanks so much @blex. For my purposes I think the original code you provided will do the trick but it's really helpful to me (as someone working on their first JavaScript app) to see both versions.

Comment: @dedaumiersmith I'm glad I could help. Good luck with your project

Comment: This saved me, after an hour of searching, thank you!