# How to enable first input focus in angular js directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How to apply this jquery in Angular directive

**Jquery**

```
$(":input:not(input[type=button],input[type=submit],button):enabled:visible:first").focus();
```

I have tried the below but no luck

**Angular Directive Link**

```
.directive('autoFocus', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: {
      autoFocusInitial: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      if (scope.autoFocusInitial == true) {

        $timeout(function () {
          element[0].querySelector("input:not(.ng-hide)").filter(":enabled:visible:first").focus();
        });
      }
    }

  };
}
```

Comment: Would be handy to see your html

Comment: Can't use the autofocus attribute instead?

Comment: @GillesC I have conditional input elements based on condition, first  element will be enabled. Finally whichever input is enabled that should be focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is the visible and enabled,

`var dom = $element[0].querySelector('input:not(.ng-hide):not(:disabled)');`

Will not select any disabled elements, `querySelector` by default will only ever grab the first one, you cannot [(with vanilla javascript by default)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom) select based on the `:visible` pseudo.

DEMO WITH VISIBILITY CHECK: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12386/

**EDIT:** As your comment suggested, you're after textarea and selects too, see my updated DEMO, however just a simple chain will suffice:

`$element[0].querySelectorAll('input:not(:disabled), textarea:not(:disabled)');`

Note: I removed the ng-hide as it now checks if it's visible or not, and seeing as ng-hide will be invisible it's pointless to add that to the request.

**EDIT 2:**

Seeing as you're wanting to bind the focus to dynamic generators such as an ng-repeat, I would conditionally tell the auto-focus when to run, IE when the ng-repeat has finished, in most cases, you should be able to run it without the ng-init or the condtion on the attribute.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12393/ or http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12394/

Comment: Thanks Hochkins. But this works only for  input elements not text area or select elements. Assume we have all the elements in one form (input, text area and select drop down) whichever is enabled in first that should get focused. but in the above demo link is not working as expected.

Comment: this works great for static forms but not  ng-repeat(dynamically created) input elements

Comment: Sorry but this is not what you asked for originally in the question, and you had no code to simulate otherwise, I would say it's your markup that's the problem not this directive because this will work anywhere, if you're inserting the inputs after the chain has already digested it will not work.

Comment: np.. thanks.. Here is sample, please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12392/

Comment: Awesome... this works great... thanks a lot Hochkins!

Comment: no problems @klmuralimohan, don't forget to hit the tick to mark my answer as correct