# Listen to element visibility in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, listener

I'm using Bootstrap and Angular 2 (v4) for my webapp. I would like to listen to an element in a directive for visibility changes. My element has a parent that can hide its children with `hidden-sm-up` and I need to trigger a function each time it is hidden or displayed.

```
div.hidden-sm-up
   input.form-control(myDirective, type='number')
```

and in my directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myDirective]'
})

export class myDirective {
    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){

    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void{
        // listen to visibility change here
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use host property of component

Comment: @BabarBilal please develop your answer...

Comment: How is it hidden or displayed? The browser doesn't provider no event when an element becomes invisible, therefore also Angular doesn't provide that.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Like mentioned in the question by using `.hidden-sm-up` in a parent.

Comment: So it's pure CSS. You can only poll by iterating parents and check the `display` property for `hidden` or whatever you apply in your CSS.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have found this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom but I don't know how to implement it as a listener...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ngDoCheck` is run when change detection is run, therefore I think it's the right place if you want to monitor it instead of just get it once at component creation time:

```
@HostListener('window:resize')
ngDoCheck() {
  this.isVisible = this.element.nativeElement.offsetParent !== null;
}
```

There might be better option, like some events that are emitted somewhere, but for the general case `ngDoCheck` should work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately `ngDoCheck` is not triggered when the browser is resized...

Comment: You can just add `@HostBinding('window:resize')` before `ngDoCheck()` and it will do.

Comment: I don't know how to use HostBinding... Should I put `ngDoCheck` inside parenthesis?

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `Can't bind to 'window:resize' since it isn't a known property of 'input'` (Please note that I have imported HostBinding from core)

Comment: Can you please try to reproduce in Plunker. I can't make any sense of this error and my code.

Comment: It should be `Hostlistener` instead of `HostBinding`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer will this cause layout thrashing?

Comment: @cambunctious I'm not sure what you mean by that exactly, but I'd say no. You might need to be careful what code you execute there, but in general I don't see a problem.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer My understanding on the topic is limited so maybe my question doesn't make sense. Does calling `offsetParent` in `ngDoCheck` force the browser to re-calculate layout? Seems like that could be problematic with the default change detection strategy. Or is the layout already calculated at that point? I understand that _modifying_ the DOM in `ngDoCheck` is probably bad.

Comment: @cambunctious I see now what you mean but I also don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I found nice blog regarding that. `HostListener` has `visible` event. https://netbasal.com/with-great-angular-components-comes-great-single-responsibility-5fa37c35ad20