# How can I check that an element is visible with Puppeteer and pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, puppeteer, visibility

I wish to check that a DOM element is visible with [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/) and pure JavaScript (not jQuery), how can I do this? By visible I mean that the element is displayed through CSS, and not hidden (f.ex. by `display: none`).

For example, I can determine whether my element `#menu` is not hidden via CSS rule `display: none`, in the following way:

```
const isNotHidden = await page.$eval('#menu', (elem) => {
  return elem.style.display !== 'none'
})
```

How can I determine in general though if the element is hidden or not, and not just through `display: none`?

Comment: I don't know how consistently it works for other methods of hiding, but `elem.getBoundingClientRect()` returns distinctive data you can test against.

Comment: @AuxTaco using```elem.getBoundingClientRect()``` returns a ```{}``` on console.log, whether the element is ready or not :(

Comment: Since Puppeteer can always run normal JS, the canonical thread [Check if element is visible in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom/21696585#21696585) should be linked because it has a huge number of resources that can be used via `.evaluate()` in Puppeteer.

Comment: @PayamB. did you try returning `JSON.stringify(elem.getBoundingClientRect())`? The reason it probably matters is that `elem.getBounding...` is a read-only [`DOMRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRect) rather than a plain object, so Puppeteer's serialization seems to be affected and doesn't capture the full object.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I found that Puppeteer has an API method for this purpose: [Page.waitForSelector](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options), via its `visible` option. I wasn't aware of the latter option, but it lets you wait until an element is visible.

```
await page.waitForSelector('#element', {
  visible: true,
})
```

Conversely you can wait for an element to be hidden, via the `hidden` option.

I think this is the idiomatic answer, with regards to the Puppeteer API. Thanks to Colin Cline though as I think his answer is probably useful as a general JavaScript solution.

Comment: This will throw if the element is not visible. If it is perfectly acceptable that the element not be visible, then throwing is NOT appropriate. I wish developers would stop throwing exceptions for normal behavior, just return a value like null!

Comment: @Gerry thats exactly my problem , i want to check for the element and then do something based on that if the element is not ready , but it throws and makes app crash when looking for the element

Comment: The question was how to test if an element is visible, not waiting for it to be added to the DOM and then to become visible, which is what this "accepted" solution does.

Comment: This doesn't work for elements that are behind other elements z-Index, though.

Comment: I don't understand how the acceptable answer is an answer that will make the script pause if the element does not exist (due to the wait)

Answer (score 15):

*One* is by checking its display style value.
*Second* is by checking its height, for exp if the element is a child of an element which is `display: none`, the `offsetHeight` will be `0` and thus you know the element is not visible despite its display value. `opacity: 0` is not considered as hidden element so we will not checking it.

```
const isNotHidden = await page.$eval('#menu', (elem) => {
    return window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue('display') !== 'none' && elem.offsetHeight
});
```

You can check `elem.offsetWidth` as well and is not bad before any calculation, check if element exist or not.

Comment: And "window" var where is defined?

Comment: @pabgaran The window object represents a window containing a DOM document; [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). You can cache the window into a variable ofc but its a global object

Comment: You're right. I'm a beginner with puppetter. All this code is working inside a "navigator", so window, document, etc are always available.

Comment: this solution just saved my day , except that i checked the height of the element .

Answer (score 10):

Use boundingBox()

This method returns the bounding box of the element (relative to the main frame), or null if the element is not visible.

API: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleboundingbox

Comment: The link in the question goes to github, but github responds with a 404. I submit a link to the same content on the pptr docs website. https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.elementhandle.boundingbox/

Answer (score 8):

The current accepted answer involves **waiting** for an element to appear **and** become visible.

If we are not interested in waiting on the element, and we would simply like to test the visibility of the element, we can use a combination of [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to test whether or not the element is visible.

We can first check that the [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) is not set to `hidden`.

Then we can validate that the bounding box is visible by checking that the `bottom`, `top`, `height`, and `width` attributes are not set to `0` (this will filter out elements that have [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) set to `none` as well).

```
const element_is_visible = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const element = document.querySelector('#example');
  const style = getComputedStyle(element);
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

  return style.visibility !== 'hidden' && !!(rect.bottom || rect.top || rect.height || rect.width);
});
```

Comment: This does not work for elements that are behind other elements (ie: stacked elements in a z-index) ... is there a full-featured solution like this that does?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can using [`elementHandle.boundingBox()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-elementhandleboundingbox) (thank to @huypham idea)

It will return a Promise that show a bounding box of the element (relative to the main frame), or null if the element is not visible.

The snippet example:

```js
      const loadMoreButton = await getDataPage.$(
        'button.ao-tour-reviews__load-more-cta.js-ao-tour-reviews__load-more-cta'
      );

      const buttonVisible = await loadMoreButton.boundingBox();

      if (buttonVisible) {
        await loadMoreButton.click().catch((e) => {
          console.log(': ' + e)
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

based on playwright's logic for checking if the element is visible - https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/master/src/server/injected/injectedScript.ts#L120-L129

```
function isVisible(element: Element): boolean {
    // Note: this logic should be similar to waitForDisplayedAtStablePosition() to avoid surprises.
    if (!element.ownerDocument || !element.ownerDocument.defaultView)
      return true;
    const style = element.ownerDocument.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element);
    if (!style || style.visibility === 'hidden')
      return false;
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.width > 0 && rect.height > 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer *@aknuds1* gave is perfect but you may make it even more convenient for yourself by creating a **helper** such as this one. This resolves to `true` if the element is visible and to `false` otherwise.

```
function isElementVisible(page, selector, timeout = 150) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        page.waitForSelector(selector, {visible: true, timeout}).then(() => {
            resolve(true);
        }).catch(() => {
            resolve(false);
        });
    });
}
```

##### Usage

in pure **JS** with **Puppeteer**

```
let isVisible = await isElementVisible(page, selector)
isVisible = await isElementVisible(page, selector, 300)
```

and if you happen to use **Jest** or another framework

```
expect(await isElementVisible(page, selector)).toBeTrue();
```

in the case of Jest (and most other frameworks), you can go even further and create a custom matcher to extend the existing ones. (https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectextendmatchers)

```
expect.extend({
    async toHaveVisible(page, selector, timeout = 150) {
        let isVisible = await isElementVisible(page, selector, timeout);

        if (isVisible) {
            return {
                message: () => `expected ${selector} not to be visible`,
                pass: true
            };
        } else {
            return {
                message: () => `expected ${selector} to be visible`,
                pass: false
            };
        }
    }
});
```

```
await expect(page).toHaveVisible(selector);
await expect(page).not.toHaveVisible(anotherSelector);
await expect(page).not.toHaveVisible(yetAnotherSelector, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently here's how jQuery does it:

```
visible = await page.evaluate((e) => e.offsetWidth > 0 && e.offsetHeight > 0, element)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if an element is visible or not then you can use this function. You should make sure that the page is ready before calling this function. You can do that by using waitForSelector on other elements you expect to be visible.

```
async function isVisible(page, selector) {
  return await page.evaluate((selector) => {
    var e = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (e) {
      var style = window.getComputedStyle(e);

      return style && style.display !== 'none' && style.visibility !== 'hidden' && style.opacity !== '0';
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }, selector);
}


// Example usage:
page.waitForSelector('#otherPeerElement');
var myElementIsVisible = await isVisible(page, '#visibleOrNot');

if (myElementIsVisible) {
// Interact with #visibleOrNot
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code definitely help you.
It basically means the element is already available on the page but is not visible yet or in CSS, the display property is set as none or visibility is hidden. Now, while writing our tests, we assume that as soon as the element is available, do an action on it like clicking or typing. But as this element is not yet visible, Puppeteer fails to perform that action.

```
async function isLocatorReady(element, page) {
  const isVisibleHandle = await page.evaluateHandle((e) => 
{
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(e);
    return (style && style.display !== 'none' && 
    style.visibility !== 'hidden' && style.opacity !== '0');
 }, element);
  var visible = await isVisibleHandle.jsonValue();
  const box = await element.boxModel();
  if (visible && box) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to utilize `Element.checkVisibility()`. It's [supported in chrome](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_checkvisibility). Here is how it works from the [css spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view-1/#dom-element-checkvisibility):

> The checkVisibility(options) method must run these steps, when called on an element this:
>
> 1. If this does not have an associated box, return false.
> 2. If a shadow-including ancestor of this has content-visibility: hidden, return false.
> 3. If the checkOpacity dictionary member of options is true, and this, or a shadow-including ancestor of this, has a computed opacity value of 0, return false.
> 4. If the checkVisibilityCSS dictionary member of options is true, and this is invisible, return false.
> 5. Return true.

Answer (score -1):

```
const firstName= await page.$('[name=firstName]')
expect(firstName!=null).equal(true)
```

Answer (score -3):

I would use @aknuds1 's approach, but you can also do the following.

```
expect((await page.$('#element')) !== null).toEqual(true)
```

If you are fetching a resource asynchronously, be aware that the above expectation may not pass, since it won't wait for the changes to reflect on the UI. That's why this approach may not be preferred in this scenario.

Comment: @Gerry you are utterly wrong. Please read the question better before you make a comment.

Comment: It appears your answer is expecting the use of a puppeteer testing framework such as jest-puppeteer and the OP did not specify they are testing.