# Count the hidden through overflow: hidden; parent children

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a photo gallery that should not display all the photos at the beginning and show how many photos were not included in the gallery (I use
 `overflow: hidden;`).

After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom), I decided to do so:

```js
const a = document.querySelectorAll('a')
const count = 0

a.forEach(el => {
  if (isHidden(el))
    count++
})

console.log('Hidden elemenets: ' + count)

function isHidden (el) {
  return el.offsetParent === null
}
```

```css
#lightgallery {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 122px;
  position: relative; /* important */
}

#lightgallery a {
  width: 176px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#lightgallery img {
  width: 100%;
}

#lightgallery a {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lightgallery">
  <a href="assets/img/light1.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=1">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light2.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=2">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light3.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=3">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light4.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=4">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light5.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=5">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light4.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=6">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light5.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=7">
  </a>
</div>
```

But it does not work.

I need to count photos that are not visible on the screen. I have a responsive design, so the gallery element can have different sizes and accordingly different users can have different number of photos.

Comment: You may want to use a `class` to do this.

Comment: In the answer, you can add a class, I simplified my httml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `class` to do that (it's much simpler to do in this way, I think).

```js
const a = document.querySelectorAll('.img-hidden')

console.log(a.length);
```

```css
#lightgallery {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 122px;
  position: relative; /* important */
}

#lightgallery a {
  width: 176px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#lightgallery img {
  width: 176px;
}

#lightgallery a {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lightgallery">
  <a href="assets/img/light1.jpg" class="img-visible">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=1">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light2.jpg" class="img-visible">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=2">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light3.jpg" class="img-visible">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=3">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light4.jpg" class="img-visible">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=4">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light5.jpg" class="img-visible">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=5">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light4.jpg" class="img-hidden">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=6">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light5.jpg" class="img-hidden">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=7">
  </a>
</div>
```

A different, more programmatic approach can be found on [this link](https://codepen.io/adam2arton/pen/MqNEJW). For this, you should explicitly set images' height, which may be not desirable for the given use-case, but does the trick, indeed.

Comment: I can only see 2 pic while this code logs `2`. So it may not be correct.

Comment: thanks, I forgot to write, I'm interested in how to count it dynamically.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько what do you mean by dynamically?

Comment: @appleapple the snippet counts all images with the classname `img-hidden` - there are exactly two of these. The script logs `2`. Can you clarify your comment please?

Comment: regardless of the size of the parent(responsive design), counts how many items are hidden.

Comment: in your code I see 3 pictures, the rest 4 are hidden, but it outputs 2

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько you mean you want dynamically count all those images that exceed the height limit and are hidden ?

Comment: I see 7 pictures, 2 of them are hidden. I don't follow you, sorry.

Comment: @AayushiKambariya Yes!

Comment: @fabrik same as what @ ИльяЗеленько said.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько sorry, I thought this question is about how to count the hidden images, not about how to display the others. Am I misunderstood your question?

Comment: I need to count photos that are not visible on the screen. I have a responsive design, so the gallery element can have different sizes and accordingly different users can have different number of photos.

Comment: can be done using Position() , scrolltop() and offset function.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько See my updated answer and the link I've provided.