# Make Div Focused And Visible In Scrollable Overflow

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, focus, visible

Is there a way to make a element inside a div that is a list of items which has scrolling to be focused. My attempts have not been successful since it does make the element focused but it will not be visible since I would have to still scroll down to view the element.

```
<style>

#list {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.item {
    width: 100%;
}

</style>

<div id="list">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item focus">Item I Want Focused</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to make the focused element visible:

```js
const focused = document.querySelector('.focus')

focused.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
```

```css
#list {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item focus">Item I Want Focused</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Is there a way to detect if an item is visible. I read up on the `scrollIntoView()` method and found out you can have it focused at the top or bottom of the scrolling list.

Comment: Look at [Check if element is visible in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19669786/5157454)