# Check if element is visible in DOM in Node.js

Tags: node.js, jsdom

I would like to check if element is visible in DOM in Node.js. I use [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) library for getting DOM structure. There are [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21696585/968379) approaches how to check element's visibility in client side javascript, but it doesn't work with jsdom in node.js.

1) [offsetParent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) property is always null, even for visible elements

2) `dom.window.getComputedStyle(el).display` returns `block`, but element's css rule is `display: none`

```
const request = require('request');
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

request({ 'https://crooked.com/podcast-series/majority-54/', jar: true }, function (e, r, b) {
  const dom = new JSDOM(b);
  test(dom);
});

const test = (dom) => {
  const hiddenElement = dom.window.document.querySelector('.search-outer-lg');
  const visibleElement = dom.window.document.querySelector('.body-tag-inner');
  console.log(dom.window.getComputedStyle(hiddenElement).display); // block
  console.log(visibleElement.offsetParent); // null
}
```

Is it possible or another way how to check element's visibility in DOM in node.js?

Comment: Can you check if you have access the `hidden` property? See: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#pretending-to-be-a-visual-browser

Comment: @k0pernikus thanks for reply. I think, I have access to `hidden` property. `dom.window.document.hidden` returns `true`. I tried to create dom structure with `pretendToBeVisual: true` option and  `dom.window.document.hidden` returns `false` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried puppeteer instead of jsdom and I got correct `display` value. Here is the snippet:

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(uri);

  const searchDiv = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const btn = document.querySelector('.search-outer-lg');
    return getComputedStyle(btn).display;
  });

  console.log(searchDiv)
  await browser.close()
})()
```

Comment: This is great. Now I am gonna explore more about puppeteer!

Answer (score 2):

Trick method :)

```
function isHiddenElement(selector) {
    return (document.querySelector(selector).offsetParent === null)
}

if(isHiddenElement('.search-outer-lg')
{
  alert("element hidden");

}
```

Answer (score -1):

try without use

```
const  a1=dom.window.document.querySelector('.search-outer-lg');
  const coponentStyle= dom.window.getComputedStyle(a1)
  coponentStyle.getPropertyValue('display')
[![const  offsetParet=window.document.querySelector('.body-tag-inner').offsetParent][1]][1]
```

it return body hav class archive tax-podcast_type term-majority-54 term-98

// it will be return none
itry this in the consle without use dom 
show this image[image: show this image]
if it not work tell me

Comment: I believe this works in client side javascript, but my question is for back-end javascript in node.js