# duplcate id's when hidding content using media query css3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

Using bootstrap 4 and vuejs
desktop has a container, with a tab pane and map. On Mobile, I remove the tab pane and just show map.

Below code is a simple representation of the problem. The tab pane and map are highly interacting on desktop. On mobile I only want to show the map with minimal interactivity because the tab pane is hidden

```
           <div class="d-sm-none">
                small
                <div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height:300px"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-none d-md-block">
                large
                <div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height:300px"></div>
            </div>
```

The div that is first, will show. For example, in the above code the map will show on mobile, but not desktop. If I rearrange the code desktop will work and mobile will not.

Below is my vue code to display map. I use leaflet.

```
           this.map = L.map('mapid', {
                center: this.center,
                zoom: this.zoom
            });
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Use different IDs? IDs must be unique, don't go against the grain, it will be an uphill battle.

Comment: I understand the id's have to be unique. I don't understand when the id is duplicated on a responsive media query? I thought the code would be hidden resulting in the removal of the id.

If I use different id's, how do I select the id in the javascript code on the media query?

Comment: The element is not removed from the DOM, it is just hidden, I've posted an answer that should address your concerns.

Comment: Thanks, let me try your solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is not to have duplicate IDs. If this is outside your control, you can pass the div directly, instead of an ID to the [Map constructor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.constructor)

You'd also need to figure out which one is visible.

```js
function getFirstVisible(els) {
  for (const el of els) {
    if (el.offsetParent) {
      return el;
    }
  }
}

const divs = document.querySelectorAll("#mapid");

// Then you could do
// this.map = L.map(getFirstVisible(divs), {center: this.center, zoom: this.zoom});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="d-sm-none">
  small
  <div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height:300px"></div>
</div>
<div class="d-none d-md-block">
  large
  <div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height:300px"></div>
</div>
```

See [Check if element is visible in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom)