# How to find whether an element is hidden or not in html and pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This question was already answered here: [Check if element is visible in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom), but I am getting an error in the correct solution first option.
It says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at isHidden (index.js:16)
    at hidde (index.js:12)
    at HTMLDocument.document.onkeypress (index.js:8)
```

This is my code:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    var key = charStr;
    hidde(<element>)
};

function hidde(element) {
    return (isHidden(element))
}

function isHidden(el) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    return (style.display === 'none')
}
```

I changed `<element>` to the element I needed to check.
Is there anything to correct?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Where does `Kitchen` come from?

Comment: how did you get `<element>`?

Comment: Kitchen in the element I wanted to check

Comment: I changed <element> to the element I needed to check.

Comment: yeah, How did you retrieve it?

Comment: Kitchen is a variable:

Comment: var Kitchen = document.getElementsByClassName("Kitchen");

Comment: Please update your question with this.

Comment: you should include that on your code above, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. so you need to pass `Kitchen[0]`

Comment: Oh I didn't check that thanks!!!

Comment: My question got solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) returns a collection. So if you are sure that it'll always return 1 element for your use case then use `elements[0]` to get the element.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('YOUR_CLASSNAME');
var element = elements[0];
```

Comment: If I say document.getElementByClassName('YOUR_CLASSNAME'); then it says that there is no function like that

Comment: Because it's `getElements` <--- THE S! It's plural! `ByClassName()`