# Delphi 11 work with TEdgeBrowser, get HTML element

Tags: html, delphi, element, delay, tedgebrowser

There is some page, which contains:

```
<input type="input" id='input_value' ...>
<button id='btn_find' ... >
<input type="checkbox" name="chbox1" ...">
```

For each string from memo1, I want:

1. put the string in input_value,
2. click on btn_find,
3. wait several seconds (until completed page loading or 3 seconds)
4. if string exist, the chbox1 appears we must click on it
5. if string doesn't exist, the chbox1 invisible we must in memo2 lines add string;
   I use TEdgeBrowser

   ```
   for i := 0 to memo1.lines.Count - 1 do    begin
    js:='document.getElementById("input_value").value="'+memo1.lines[i]+'"';
    EdgeBrowser1.ExecuteScript(js);
    EdgeBrowser1.ExecuteScript('document.getElementById("btn_find").click()');
    Delay(3000);
    // here I must check if the chbox1 visible 
   if {chbox1 visible} then
      EdgeBrowser1.ExecuteScript('document.getElementsByName("chbox1")[0].click()')
      else memo2.lines.add(memo1.lines[i]);
    end;
   ```

Comment: [Check if element is visible in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19669786/4299358) answers this for the JS part. To check results per `.ExecuteScript( 'return "mytext";' )` see [an example](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/execute-scripts-and-view-source-with-tedgebrowser/) of using the [`OnExecuteScript`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Edge.TCustomEdgeBrowser.OnExecuteScript) event.