Polyfill for the browser checkVisibility function
I'm working on a project that leverages a third party library, which uses the checkVisibility() function.
I have a few users reporting errors and console is showing TypeError: checkVisibility is not a function.
Looks like this shipped in Safari 17.4, (March 2024).
I tried to look but couldn't find an existing polyfill. Maybe I should just write it myself? Is there a good way to understand this spec so that I can make sure my polyfill would work as intended? Looking for suggestions on how I should handle this issue without removing the third party library I'm already using.
Thank you!

I'm looking for the same thing. I think we should just check visibility, opacity, display, and maybe offsetWidth. This post has some options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom

Was looking for the same thing, you can find spec here. https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view-1/#dom-element-checkvisibility. Had chatgpt write a polyfill using this spec and it seems to work atteast for my use-case.
