# Toggle button not working. Not having display: none; at first click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a toggle button with js, but the first time it's clicked it is not working. Since the `nav.display.display` has no value although it has `display: none;` in the CSS code.

I guess there should be an issue on how I'm using onload... as if the css wasn't loaded yet. But I've read that `window.onload` waits for all to load. So I don't really know what's happening.

This is how I'm loading it, in real code (outside jsfiddle that handles onload)

```
window.onload = function() {
    var el = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle');
    el.addEventListener("click", toggleNav, false);
};
```

**NO jQuery please.**

Here's the jsfiddle:

```js
function toggleNav() {
  var nav = document.querySelector('#navigation');
  alert(nav.style.display);
  
  if (nav.style.display == 'none') {
    nav.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    nav.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
var el = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle');
el.addEventListener("click", toggleNav, false);
```

```css
#navigation {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="nav-toggle">Toggle</button>
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: add <nav id="navigation" style='display:none'> to your html

Comment: Yeah, that way the DOM has the display property. And it works. But what If I don't want to use style="" attribute ?

Comment: If you want to keep the "display:none" in the css you can add a check for offsetWidth and offsetHeight as seen here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19808107/407526

Comment: @Aliester I would consider making that an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Aliester ;)

Comment: Just for fun, here is a somewhat hacky, pure CSS version: https://jsfiddle.net/k5yym7ng/

Comment: @Jeflopo if you don't want to use the style attribute then you shouldn't be using JavaScript because JS is adding this attribute to your element. This is the reason that it doesn't work first time. JavaScript can't find the attribute so it needs to set it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access style via [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead of `style`

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle'),
    nav = document.getElementById('navigation');
    
btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (window.getComputedStyle(nav, null).display == 'none') {
    nav.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    nav.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
#navigation {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="nav-toggle">Toggle</button>
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Kudos for you, I think it's better to use `getComputedStyle()` than relying on elements size. Thank you too.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Aliester comment I figured it out :)

```js
function toggleNav() {
  var nav = document.getElementById('navigation');
  
  if (nav.offsetWidth == 0 && nav.offsetHeight == 0) {
    nav.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    nav.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
var el = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle');
el.addEventListener("click", toggleNav, false);
```

```css
#navigation {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="nav-toggle">Toggle</button>
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Disply:none on your `#navigation` hope this one works.

```js
function toggleNav() {
  var nav = document.getElementById('navigation');
  
  
  if (nav.style.display == 'none') {
    nav.style.display = 'block';
    
  } else {
    nav.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
var el = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle');
el.addEventListener("click", toggleNav, false);
```

```css
#navigation {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="nav-toggle">Toggle</button>
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: It works. But I would prefer to not use style="" attribute.

Comment: The current answer doesn't works. The first time you click display has no value. So we have to click twice to show.

Comment: **First time** click not working its working after **twice** click.